# I'm trying to remove substrings from a string using recursion in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This is the code I got so far but it's not working as intended and I'm not sure what's making the problem.

```py
def removeSubstrings(s, sub):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ''
    if sub == s[0]:
        return removeSubstrings(s[1:], s)
    else:
        return s[0] + removeSubstrings(s[1:], sub)
```

This is the tester program:

```py
from recursion import *
allPassed = True

def removeSubstringsMain():
    global allPassed
    
    testCases = [(1, 'abcdef', 'abc', 'def'),
                 (2, 'abcdef', 'def', 'abc'),
                 (3, 'abcdef', 'bcd', 'aef'),
                 (4, 'abcdef', '', 'abcdef'),
                 (5, 'abcdef', 'abcdef', ''), 
                 (6, 'aabbaabb', 'aa', 'bbbb'),
                 (7, 'abcdef', 'xyz', 'abcdef'),
                 (8, 'aabbaabb', 'a', 'bbbb')]
    
    for num, message, substring, expected in testCases:
        result = removeSubstrings(message, substring)
        if result != expected:
            print(f'Remove Substrings Test {num} Failed. Expected {expected} got {result}')
            allPassed = False

def main():
    removeSubstringsMain()
  #  closestMain()   ignore    
 #   strDistMain()   ignore
    if allPassed:
        print('All tests passed')

    
main()
```

This is the error mesagess that's coming from the tester:

> ```
> Remove Substrings Test 1 Failed. Expected def got abcdef
> Remove Substrings Test 2 Failed. Expected abc got abcdef
> Remove Substrings Test 3 Failed. Expected aef got abcdef
> Remove Substrings Test 5 Failed. Expected  got abcdef
> Remove Substrings Test 6 Failed. Expected bbbb got aabbaabb
> Remove Substrings Test 8 Failed. Expected bbbb got abbaabb
> ```

Comment: `if sub == s[0]:` -- that checks if the first character of your message equals the whole substring.  That is definitely not what you want.  Surely you need to use `s.find(sub)`, and then take action depending on what was returned.

Comment: If you want to test if the string begins with the substring use `if s.startswith(sub):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if sub == s[0]:
```

tests if the first character is the substring. This will only work if the substring is only 1 character long.

You can use `startswith()` to test if the substring is at the beginning of `s`. Then you'll need to slice off the entire substring when recursing.

You'll need to treat an empty substring as a base case, since all strings start with an empty string, but removing it doesn't change anything, so that will be an infinite loop.

```
def removeSubstrings(s, sub):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ''
    if len(sub) == 0:
        return s
    if s.startswith(sub):
        return removeSubstrings(s[len(sub):], sub)
    else:
        return s[0] + removeSubstrings(s[1:], sub)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of your function removeSubstrings, why not use the inbuilt string replace?

```
result = message.replace(substring, "")
```

Comment: the intention was to use a recursive function

Answer (score -1):

Looks like someone already gave you a good answer. Here's mine. Similar approach, but using slices larger than one character.

```
def removeSubstrings(s, sub) -> str:
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ''

    loc = s.find(sub)

    if loc == -1 or sub == '':
        return s

    return removeSubstrings(s[:loc], sub) + removeSubstrings(s[loc+len(sub):], sub)
```